# Why is jQuery not working on appended content?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a jQuery function that displays a hidden content on each element in the loop of elements. This work perfectly, but the problem is that when I append new elements to the loop it stops working. It actually works on some elements and doesn't work on others (strange behavior).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

 $(".see_all").click(function(){

 if ($(this).next().css('display') == 'none'){
 $(this).next().show();

}
else

if($(this).next().is(':visible')){
   $(this).next().hide();
 }

});
})
</script>
```

Is there a problem with my jQuery code? How can I make it work on both newly appended elements and previously displayed elements.

**HTML code**

```
   <div class="center_container">
   <%for users in @user%>
  <div class="see_all">

  <span style="color:#808080;cursor:pointer">See All Reviews(<%=@beep_count=       (@beep.opposes.count +  @beep.neutrals.count + @beep.supports.count)%>)</span>

 </div>

     <div style="display:none;" class="hidden">

      No reviews available 

     </div>
 <%end%>

 </div>
```

Comment: You mean when there are dynamically appended html , the jquery events do not fire ?

Comment: You forgot a ; in the last line .

Comment: Please mention the `jQuery` version you're using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*This will only work if you're using jQ 1.7+*. If you're not, take a look at jQuery's 
[delegate method](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), which will achieve the same thing in jQuery < 1.7. There's no reason not to be using the latest version, though :)

This is because at the time when you bind your click handler:

```
 $(".see_all").click()
```

It is bound *only* to the current elements that match the selector `.see_all`.

What you can do to get around this is use jQuery's `on()` to delegate:

```
$("body").on("click", ".see_all", function() {
  //do stuff
});
```

This handler is bound to the `body`, and then when it detects a click it will look to see if the element clicked matches the selector `.see_all`. If it does, it will then execute the function. Because it's bound to the `body`, this will work if new `.see_all` elementsare inserted into the DOM too.

If all `.see_all` are contained within one `div`, use that to delegate on rather than `body` - used that purely as an example. Delegate to the first thing that encompasses all `.see_all` elements.

As a side note, you should use the new API `.on()` and `.off()` for your event binding, since 1.7 they have become the preferred method. [Documentation for .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: i have tried your solution but i doesn't respond. I use jquery 1.7.1 so i tried used delegate but it didn't work :(

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're not using 1.8? Or at least 1.7?

Comment: sorry mistake about the jQuery version

Comment: With 1.7.1 you should be fine to use `on()`

Comment: i tried doing this                                $("body").on("click", ".see_all", function() {
if ($(this).next().css('display') == 'none'){
$(this).next().show();
}
else
if($(this).next().is(':visible')){
 $(this).next().hide();
 }
});                                                                     but it didnt work.

Comment: then i tried this                                   $(".center_container").on("click", ".see_all", function() {
if ($(this).next().css('display') == 'none'){
$(this).next().show();
}
else
if($(this).next().is(':visible')){
 $(this).next().hide();
 }
});                                                                 and it still didn't work :(.........pls help

Answer (score 2):

First of all, this can be optimized using toggle. Then, you will need an on() event handler for this, since click is only bound to already existing elements on document ready. When a new element is added, you need a way to dynamically re-bind the click event.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

 $("body").on('click', '.see_all', function(){
  $(this).next().toggle();
});
})
</script>
```